# Not able to fetch values of picklist from inside Apex:Repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to access the values of a selected radio button from inside an `apex:repeat`. But when I try to get the values the values return null for the radio options. The visualforce code I have used is given below.

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!lstQuestions}" var="questions" id="theRepeat">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" frame="box" rules="rows" columnClasses="col1,col2,col3" id="theGrid">
        <apex:outputText > 1 </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText > {!questions.Question__c} </apex:outputText>
        <apex:selectRadio id="r1" styleClass="radio" label="" value="{!questions.Answer__c}">
            <apex:selectOptions itemLabel="Correct" ItemValue="Correct" />
            <apex:selectOptions itemLabel="Incorrect" ItemValue="Incorrect" />
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:repeat>
```

lstQuestions is of the object Feedback_Questions__c and contains instances of object. After selection when I iterate and check for the answers they are not loaded. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What type is the `Answer__c` field? Maybe instead of use `selectRadio` you can try `apex:inputField`

Comment: Answer__c is a text field. And if I have apex:inputField then the user will be able to enter values, which I do not want as there are only 2 answers Correct or Incorrect.

Comment: what event on the page is causing the selected radio button value(s) to be sent to the controller? Does it have an action=immediate ? Have you looked to see if the setters on controller property `lstQuestions` are getting invoked

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `apex:selectOptions` you have to use `apex:selectOption` tag:

```
    <apex:selectRadio id="r1" styleClass="radio" label="" value="{!questions.Answer__c}">
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Correct" ItemValue="Correct" />
        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Incorrect" ItemValue="Incorrect" />
    </apex:selectRadio>
```

The `apex:selectOptions` tag need to have a merge field that references the controller class **collection variable**. And the `apex:selectOption` can be used without that collection.

Comment: I changed it to apex:selectOption but still when I try to print getting the value for the field as null...